# How to read new function in Laravel with InfyOm Laravel Generator?

Tags: php, laravel, generator, laravel-5.3

I've made a controller, model, view etc using InfyOm Laravel Generator.

I run: `php artisan infyom:scaffold Hotel`

I got this command from: http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/5.3/getting-started#generator-commands

It generates the controller, model, view etc

The controller Hotel like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\CreatehotelRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdatehotelRequest;
use App\Repositories\hotelRepository;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppBaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Flash;
use Prettus\Repository\Criteria\RequestCriteria;
use Response;

class hotelController extends AppBaseController
{
    /** @var  hotelRepository */
    private $hotelRepository;

    public function __construct(hotelRepository $hotelRepo)
    {
        $this->hotelRepository = $hotelRepo;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the hotel.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $this->hotelRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
        $hotels = $this->hotelRepository->all();

        return view('hotels.index')
            ->with('hotels', $hotels);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new hotel.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        die('hotel view');
        return view('hotels.create');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        die('test view');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created hotel in storage.
     *
     * @param CreatehotelRequest $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(CreatehotelRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $hotel = $this->hotelRepository->create($input);

        Flash::success('Hotel saved successfully.');

        return redirect(route('hotels.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified hotel.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $hotel = $this->hotelRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($hotel)) {
            Flash::error('Hotel not found');

            return redirect(route('hotels.index'));
        }

        return view('hotels.show')->with('hotel', $hotel);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified hotel.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $hotel = $this->hotelRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($hotel)) {
            Flash::error('Hotel not found');

            return redirect(route('hotels.index'));
        }

        return view('hotels.edit')->with('hotel', $hotel);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified hotel in storage.
     *
     * @param  int              $id
     * @param UpdatehotelRequest $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id, UpdatehotelRequest $request)
    {
        $hotel = $this->hotelRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($hotel)) {
            Flash::error('Hotel not found');

            return redirect(route('hotels.index'));
        }

        $hotel = $this->hotelRepository->update($request->all(), $id);

        Flash::success('Hotel updated successfully.');

        return redirect(route('hotels.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified hotel from storage.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $hotel = $this->hotelRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($hotel)) {
            Flash::error('Hotel not found');

            return redirect(route('hotels.index'));
        }

        $this->hotelRepository->delete($id);

        Flash::success('Hotel deleted successfully.');

        return redirect(route('hotels.index'));
    }
}
```

I call the URL like this: http://localhost/adminlte-generator/public/hotels/create, and the result is : hotel view

I add new function, The function is Test. Then I call the URL like this: http://localhost/adminlte-generator/public/hotels/test. It's not displaying the test view.

Is there any solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at laravel routing

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing

You must register it on your route

example (this should be apply on your route/web.php)

`Route::get('adminlte-generator/public/hotels', ['uses' => 'hotelController@test']);`

I have suspicions of how `/create` is working. Maybe they provided the route::resource for you when you run artisan command. I'm not sure about it. :)

**Edit**

Try first this:

```
Route::get('adminlte-generator/public/hotels', function() {
    echo 'Working.';
});
```

Access the route and if you see working. The problem is on your controller.

The try to add this on your route:

```
public function test() {
    echo 'Working in controller.';
}
```

This can help you to find/identify the error.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had register it in my route. But, it's not working

Comment: No error. But when I call `http://localhost/adminlte-generator/public/hotels/test`, It's not display `test view`, but it's back to `http://localhost/adminlte-generator/public/hotels`

Comment: It's impossible that there's no error if it's not working. If there's no error, it means that your application is running. After 1year working with laravel projects. I'd never encounter same circumstance as yours. Sorry, I can't help you. ** deleting this answer in a minute **

Comment: Do not remove your answer. it looks like your answer is correct. I may be less rigorous. I'll try again

Comment: For me the answer is right. Infyom provides scaffold/api controllers and adds resource routes. If you add any new funtion to them, you have to provide route.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895, I add : `Route::get('adminlte-generator/public/hotels', ['uses' => 'hotelController@test']);` in route/web.php, it back to `http://localhost/adminlte-generator/public/hotels`. It is no display `test view`

Comment: I try again edit to be : `Route::get('hotels', ['uses' => 'hotelController@test']);`, there is exist error like this : `Route [hotels.index] not defined.`

Comment: You try to clone/download this : https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/adminlte-generator/tree/5.3 and try it. it does not work

Comment: Don;t give up, I also had some problems with routes recently. Expand syntax a little: Route::get('adminlte-generator/public/hotels', ['as'=>'public-hotels', 'uses' => 'hotelController@test']) . Use the 'public-hotels'  to get the route.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895, Are you sure it works? you've tried? I've tried it and it did not work

Comment: when nothing works I just run php artisan optimize and composer dump-autoload , , but for sure, now you have issue with route only